# using res.sendfile for using the content of a file in the scope of a controller

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I need to use the content of files that will be served from the server in the scope of a controller in an angular.js node.js application.

i am using res.sendfile in my node.js to serve a file that is being asked from my client angular.js

now i need to get access to the actual content (text) of the file being served.

this is my code in my client:

```
$scope.getFile= function(path){
    FileService.file.get({filePath: path}, function(data){
        //do something with the incoming file
        console.log(data);
    }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

now for some reason the data that is being sent is returned as an array, so i recieve a huge array with the file content, while i just need the whole content to be inserted into a scope variable for use. what are my options here? should i do something else on my server? or maybe in my client?
is my only option is to actually read the file on the server to stream it as an object back to the client?
it is not possible to return an object with res.sendfile

thanks.

Comment: what does your return object look like and what part you will use in your application?

Comment: if i log it to console i recieve: 
Resource: {0: "<", 1: "!"................}
just an array of chars.
i want to be able to grab all the text and put it in a scope variable